# The readonly keyword in c# for fields of an object

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

It's said that when constructing an object, the initialization order is:

1. Fields are given default values (for example for an reference type the value "null" is given, for numeric values "0" is given)

2. Then the constructor is called. If we have a non-parameterless constructor, how could it be possible to initialize private fields with the parameters? (I suppose that the fields are already initialized with their default values, since they are "readonly", once they are given a value, their value shouldn't be modified afterwards).

Please correct me if I get it wrong.

Comment: Unclear what the question is. Please explain using a [mcve]

Comment: int type = 0 instead of int type { get; set; }

Comment: perhaps you can try reading here [C# MSDN Read-Only Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) once again.. `Good Luck`

Comment: (puts on moderator hat) - k; some comments got out of line here and have been deleted; can we all please *play nicely* - thanks. Let's keep the comments constructive and about the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: `readonly` here means that it can't be set (at least, not without cheating) after construction. There is no conflict here with having both a field initializer *and* a constructor-assigned value.

In reality, though: `readonly` is a lie and is only enforced if you play nicely.

Answer (score 3):

As per the C# Language Specification:

> **Section 10.5.2 Readonly fields** When a field-declaration includes a readonly modifier, the fields introduced by the declaration are
>   readonly fields. Direct assignments to readonly fields can only occur
>   as part of that declaration or in an instance constructor or static
>   constructor in the same class. (A readonly field can be assigned to
>   multiple times in these contexts.) Specifically, direct assignments to
>   a readonly field are permitted only in the following contexts:
>
> - In the variable-declarator that introduces the field (by including a variable-initializer in the declaration).
> - **For an instance field, in the instance constructors of the class that contains the field declaration; for a static field**, in the static
>     constructor of the class that contains the field declaration. These
>     are also the only contexts in which it is valid to pass a readonly
>     field as an out or ref parameter.

So basically, you *can* initialise readonly fields in the constructor.